# Looping timer/progress bar in batch file fails on the second loop, counts down into the negatives

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a chunk of code with a series of commands to essentially make a progress bar in the title of the console. It shows the seconds remaining on a timer and a progressive "Working. . ." animation where it adds dots until it hits three before looping back to one. The idea is to start a .exe file, wait for a timer to count down to zero, then start another .exe and count down before ending the script, looping twice in total.

When run, the first startup (for the server) goes through smoothly, it counts down and echoes "Finished" to the console before moving on. When it tries the second startup (for the launcher) however, it continues counting down past zero and into the negatives without ever running the code after the `if %loopcount%==0` line, presumably because it never triggers. You can see it [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovqhe.jpg)

I've tried a handful of different things to get this to work, most notably copy and pasting the loop code for both launches and eliminating the `set serverstatus=0` and `if %serverstatus%==1` system entirely, but no luck.

Here's a cut down version of the code that can run on its own and has the same issue as the main file:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims==" %%G in (variables.txt) do set %%G
rem pulls variables listed in 'variables.txt' and defines them

:serverstart

set serverstatus=0
ECHO Starting Server ^(Aki.Server.exe^)...
@start Aki.Server.exe

if %driveType%==0 (
        echo Working... ^(%serverStartTimeSSD% Seconds, Using SSD Preset^)
        set loopcount=%serverStartTimeSSD%
        
) else if %driveType%==1 (
        echo Working... ^(%serverStartTimeHDD% Seconds, Using HDD Preset^)
        set loopcount=%serverStartTimeHDD%
)
:loop
        title Console - Saru's SPT Auto ^Start Script - WORKING.      (%loopcount% Seconds Remaining)
                rem timeout code
                rem the next three lines add a 1sec delay
                for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('
                timeout /t 1 /nobreak 2^>Nul
                ') do echo | break
        set /a loopcount=loopcount-1
        title Console - Saru's SPT Auto ^Start Script - WORKING. .    (%loopcount% Seconds Remaining)
                rem timeout code
                for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('
                timeout /t 1 /nobreak 2^>Nul
                ') do echo | break
        set /a loopcount=loopcount-1
        title Console - Saru's SPT Auto ^Start Script - WORKING. . .  (%loopcount% Seconds Remaining)
                rem timeout code
                for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('
                timeout /t 1 /nobreak 2^>Nul
                ') do echo | break
        set /a loopcount=loopcount-1

        if %loopcount%==0 echo Finished. && if %serverstatus%==0 goto :launcherstart
        goto :loop

:launcherstart

if %serverstatus%==1 goto :endstartup
ECHO Starting Launcher ^(Aki.Launcher.exe^)...
@start Aki.Launcher.exe
if %driveType%==0 (
        echo Working... ^(%launcherStartTimeSSD% Seconds, Using SSD Preset^)
        set loopcount=%launcherStartTimeSSD%
        set serverstatus=1
        goto :loop
        
) else if %driveType%==1 (
        echo Working... ^(%launcherStartTimeHDD% Seconds, Using HDD Preset^)
        set loopcount=%launcherStartTimeHDD%
        set serverstatus=1
        goto :loop
)

:endstartup
echo All processes finished.
pause
```

And here's my `variables.txt` file:

```
directory=C:/SinglePlayerTarkov
serverStartTimeSSD=6
serverStartTimeHDD=40
launcherStartTimeSSD=5
launcherStartTimeHDD=10
showErrorCodes=1
driveType=0
```

the `showErrorCodes` variable shouldn't be relevant to this, but I've included it for the sake of being thorough.

Probably the weirdest thing of all here is that if I swap the launcher and server startup order, (excluding the `set serverstatus=0` and `if %serverstatus%==1 goto :endstartup` lines) the timer glitch happens first instead of second. Essentially, **the timer only counts into the negatives when starting the launcher,** despite the fact that the code for both the launcher and server startups are identical aside from the variables used. Changing those variables or even removing them outright in favor of integers doesn't seem to make a difference either.

I've been staring at this for hours now, a **suggestion** alone would make my week, let alone a solution. Thanks for taking the time to read all this, it turned out a whole lot longer than I thought it would.

Comment: It's not clear whether your (eg) `::timeout code, ^these three lines delay the next piece of commands by one second` is actually within your code or (explanatory notes). `::` is a broken label and breaks `code blocks` (parenthesised lines of code). Replace the `::` with `rem ` to overcome this gotcha.

Comment: @Magoo Thanks for the help, I've edited the post and my code to replace them. If you have any other insight as to how I could fix the issue it would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
for /f "tokens=* delims==" %%G in (q75839960.txt) do set %%G
rem pulls variables listed in 'variables.txt' and defines them

:serverstart

set serverstatus=0
ECHO Starting Server (Aki.Server.exe^)...
:: start Aki.Server.exe

if %driveType%==0 (
 echo Working... (%serverStartTimeSSD% Seconds, Using SSD Preset^)
 set loopcount=%serverStartTimeSSD%
) 
if %driveType%==1 (
  echo Working... (%serverStartTimeHDD% Seconds, Using HDD Preset^)
  set loopcount=%serverStartTimeHDD%
)


:loop
title Console - Saru's SPT Auto ^Start Script - WORKING.      (%loopcount% Seconds Remaining)
rem timeout code
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
set /a loopcount=loopcount-1

if %loopcount% gtr 0 GOTO loop
echo Finished.

:launcherstart

if %serverstatus%==1 goto endstartup
ECHO Starting Launcher (Aki.Launcher.exe^)...
:: @start Aki.Launcher.exe
set serverstatus=1
if %driveType%==0 (
 echo Working... (%launcherStartTimeSSD% Seconds, Using SSD Preset^)
 set loopcount=%launcherStartTimeSSD%
) 
if %driveType%==1 (
 echo Working... (%launcherStartTimeHDD% Seconds, Using HDD Preset^)
 set loopcount=%launcherStartTimeHDD%
)
goto loop

:endstartup
echo All processes finished.
PAUSE
GOTO :EOF
```

Your fundamental problem is that the delay loop is 3 seconds, so in order to have `loopcount` exactly equal zero, its initial value must be a multiple of 3.

There appears to be no reason that you could not simply reduce the delay to 1 sec.

You could leave your original 3 sec delay in place; using `gtr` will loop if `loopcount` is greater than `0`.

Your interpretation of `drivetype` seems to be overly complex. I've simplified it. The top section sets `servertatus` to `0`, then goes to `loop`. The revised lower section now does the same.

You haven't taken into consideration the possibility that `drivetype` is neither `0` nor `1`. This may or may not be relevant.

I've commented-out the `start` code since I don't have those executables and changed the `variables.txt` filename to suit my system.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It seems much more simple now - I'm sure working on this so late at night didn't help anything though. I'll mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0):

### Update: I've found the issue.

The long and short of it is that the `if %loopcount%==0 ...` check only ran once in the command loop. Note, I use "timer" and "loopcount/loopcount value" interchangeably.

The commands in the loop went like this:

`change the title, pause for 1 second, subtract 1 from the %loopcount% value` **x3**

`check if %loopcount% value equals 0` **x1**

`loop.` **x1**

The issue here is that the `if %loopcount%==0` command runs only once in the loop, **after** all three title updates and value subtractions.

The `if %loopcount%==0` statement checks if the `%loopcount%` value equals **exactly** zero, and because the check essentially only runs every three seconds, the timer can go past zero before the if statement is run and count down past zero. By this point, the check will fail and be ignored since the `%loopcount%` value is now a negative number and not zero. The only reason the timer worked for the first loop is because it's value was set to six, which is divisible by three. By coincidence, the counter hit zero exactly when the if statement was run, letting it move forwards.

There are two solutions here;

1. Modify the `if %loopcount%==0` statement to check if the `%loopcount%` value is **less than or equal** to zero (`if %loopcount% leq 0`), rather than just equal. This solution has the downside of still potentially counting down past 0 if the timer value is not divisible by 3, since the check still only occurs every 3 seconds.
2. (Best solution.) Copy the `if %loopcount%==0` statement and paste it after every `set /a loopcount=loopcount-1` command in the loop, so that the check runs after every timer update. This works perfectly, although it clutters up the code quite a bit.

tl;dr, The `if %loopcount%==0` statement only runs every three seconds, so if the timer counts down past zero before then, when the if statement runs, the value will be a negative value that doesn't equal 0 and the check will fail. Replace `if %loopcount%==0` with `if %loopcount% leq 0` **OR** copy and paste `if %loopcount%==0` after every `set /a loopcount=loopcount-1` subtraction statement.